# How do you access a class method that is hold by a shared pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am a new C++ student, so I probably don't fully understand smart pointers yet.

I thought that you can access a class-method through a shared_ptr (in this case, created through `weak_ptr.lock()`) with `->`?

But, for some reason, the program seems to terminate in the process:

```
class Student{
  string name;
public:
  Student(string name):name(name){}
  string get_name()const{return name;}
  virtual ~Student()=default;
};

class Lecture {
  map<string, weak_ptr<Student>> person;
  string name;
public:
  Lecture(const string& name, const Student& bi): name(name){
    weak_ptr<Student>w = std::make_shared<Student>(bi);
    person.insert({name, w});
  }

  // this is the cout-overload that does not work properly
  ostream& print(ostream& o)const{
    o<<name<<endl;
    map<string, weak_ptr<Student>>::const_iterator itr;
    for(itr=person.begin();itr!=person.end();itr++){
      // the line below is the problem
      o<<itr->second.lock()->get_name()<<endl;
    }
    return o;
  }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Lecture& c){
  return c.print(o);
}
```

This is the main:

```
int main()
{
    Student Carl("Carl");
    Lecture Anatomy("Anatomy", Carl);
    cout<<Anatomy<<endl;
    cout<<"This line does not get printed anymore!";
}
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Obvious question is why you are using weak_ptr, why not shared_ptr (which seems more appropriate).

Comment: Basically your object is getting destroyed because the only reference to it is a weak pointer. That's how weak pointers work. If you had a shared pointer in your map then it wouldn't get destoyed.

Comment: Tip: Try and keep your class names in the form `Student` and variables all lower-case like `carl` to avoid confusing `Carl` with a class named "Carl".

Comment: _"the program seems to terminate"_ What does the debugger say about this termination?

Comment: Tell me, does `itr->second.lock()` return a null pointer or a not-null pointer?

Comment: You _ALWAYS_ need to check the result of `weak_ptr<T>::lock()` to make sure it didn't return a null pointer.

Comment: The "make" in `make_shared` is "creational" – think "make me a pizza", not "make me a millionaire". There is no point in creating a new shared student for each lecture. If you want to share students among lectures, you need to create shared students that you can pass to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access it like this:

> ```
> o<<itr->second.lock()->get_name()<<endl;
> ```

Now why doesn't it work? Well, you didn't have any shared_ptrs pointing at your object any more. So it got deleted.

Since the object was deleted, `itr->second.lock()` returned a null pointer. Then you tried to use the null pointer, which crashed your program.